# Sitemap file not getting deployed to Azure website

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, sitemap

I'm running an ASP.NET Core (formerly ASP.NET 5) website on Azure.

I updated my sitemap file a couple months ago and in checking Google Webmaster Tools, I noticed that there were a few errors in my sitemap. I checked what GWT showed for the contents and found out it's from my previous version.

I've checked my BitBucket repository and see that the correct, updated version lives there.

Why isn't Azure deploying my updated version?

Edit: in response to the commenter below...

Here's the project.json file:

```
{
  "userSecretsId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "compilationOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "Dapper": "1.42.0",
    "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNet": "1.0.0-rc1",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework": "3.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.CodeGenerators.Mvc": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileProviderExtensions": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "HtmlAgilityPack": "1.4.9.5"
  },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel",
    "ef": "EntityFramework.Commands"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework": "1.0.0-*"
      }
    }
  },

  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "publishExclude": [
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "npm install", "bower install", "gulp clean", "gulp min" ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Is your sitemap file included in your `publishOptions` inside your `project.json` file?

Comment: No idea, I'll check that out...

Comment: @JérômeMével I updated my question with the entire project.json file. Looks like I don't have that section at all. But it does have the publishExclude section, and neither of those paths would match the sitemap file, and its still not deploying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So that's strange you don't have any `publishOptions` section in your `project.json`. You should include it. For example mine looks like this and I added your `sitemap.xml` to the list (I don't know where your file is so I assume it's at the root level)

```js
"publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "web.config",
      "appsettings.Development.json",
      "appsettings.Production.json",
      "Views",
      "sitemap.xml"
    ]
}
```

By the way, your `project.json` looks very old, you are still using RC1. Lots of things changed since then, after that RC2 came then RTM 1.0 and few days ago version 1.1.0.
I really advise you to upgrade your project, RC1 was a very early stage version, you should not keep using it. It will take some time to upgrade it but it's worth it

Comment: Thanks, I'll try adding the publisngOptions section for now. The upgrade I have on my todo list, but was working on getting most of the bugs out of my site before that. By the way, you have a good link that details the upgrade path from RC1 to Core 1.1?

Comment: RC1 has lots of bugs and limitations too, so I suggest this task should be at the very top of your to-do list. .NET Core 1.1 is still preview version for the moment so I think you would better upgrade to 1.0 first. The biggest changes gap is between RC1 and RC2 in my opinion. I haven't upgraded from RC1 directly to 1.0, I followed the versions as they went out. So I personally did RC1 -> RC2 -> 1.0. You can try [this link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/rc1-to-rtm) I think the best would be to create a brand new 1.0 project and then port all your controllers and classes

Comment: So I just got done upgrading to ASP.NET Core, I added that and it still didn't work. Weird thing is, the deployment script log shows that it copied the files: KuduSync.NET from: 'D:\local\Temp\8d4xxxxxxxxxx0a' to: 'D:\home\site\wwwroot'
Copying file: 'robots.txt'
Copying file: 'sitemap.xml'

Comment: Ensure the files are really where they are supposed to be, don't rely just on your deployment script output. Instead of deploying it to Azure directly you can also try to deploy in a local folder using `dotnet publish` and then run your application with `dotnet YourApplication.dll`
If publishing and running locally works and your files are really on your Azure VM then the problem must be some access rights for static files at this location.

Answer (score 1):

For ASP.NET Core 2.0, add the robots.txt file to the wwwroot folder